# Another "JButtons only appear after mouse over"

Tags: jbutton, mouseover

The problem is mentioned in the title. I looked for a solution but nothing worked. repaint(), revalidate() before pack() - just no effect.

Has anyone an idea what's the problem? I do not override the paint() method or something like that.

Here is  my code:

```
public class Ui extends JFrame{

public Ui() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    getContentPane().removeAll();

    pHeader = new Header();
    pHeader.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    pMap = new Map();
    pMap.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    pMap.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(20, 20));

    pBase = new Base();
    pBase.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setText("Hallo");
    button.add(pHeader);
    button.setVisible(true);

    add(pHeader, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(pBase, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(pMap, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Map-Class:

```
public class Map extends JPanel {

private Folk folk = new Folk();
private Field[][] field = new Field[20][20];

public static Random rnd = new Random();

public Map() {
    for(int row = 0; row < field.length; row++) {
        for(int column = 0; column < field[row].length; column++) {
            Field f = new Field(row,column,setFieldType(row, column)) {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(30, 30);
                }
            };
            field[row][column]=f;               
            if(f.getType() == 0) { f.setBackground(new Color(153,204,255)); }           //light blue
            else if(f.getType() == 6) { f.setBackground(new Color(128,255,0)); }        //light green
            else if(f.getType() == 11) { f.setBackground(new Color(0,102,51)); }        //dark green
            else if(f.getType() == 12) { f.setBackground(new Color(0,102,51)); }        //dark green
            else if(f.getType() == 13) { f.setBackground(new Color(102,204,51)); }      //green
            else if(f.getType() == 20) { f.setBackground(Color.GRAY); }                 //grey
            else { f.setBackground(new Color(128,255,0)); }                             //light green

            add(f);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Okay guys, after 2 days I finally found the error. The JButton class "Field" had the 
methods getX() and getY()
which overrides the swing functions!

Comment: You can post the solution into an answer.